# Замена определенного тэга при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, на обработку поступает текст примера:

`привет здесь будет <img src="/images/buttons/[здесь цифры от 0 до 40 из цикла].jpg" class="wrbtn"> картинка`

как можно при помощи регулярного выражения заменить этот текст на текст такого типа: `привет здесь будет <button>1</button> картинка`

я пытался набросать регулярку исходя из своих знаний, но потратив несколько часов получалось только что-то непонятное

Comment: Добавте в вопрос то, что получилось.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var string = 'привет здесь будет <img src="/images/buttons/[здесь цифры от 0 до 40 из цикла].jpg" class="wrbtn"> картинка';
var result = string.replace(/<img.*[\/](.*)[\.].*[>]/ig, '<button>$1</button>');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var string = 'привет здесь будет <img src="/images/buttons/36.jpg" class="wrbtn"> картинка';
var result = string.replace(/<img\s+[^>]+?(\d+)\.jpg[^>]*>/ig, '<button>$1</button>');
console.log(result);
```